# Why was identify-this-game question closed?

Tags: discussion, closing

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27802/whats-this-multiplayer-game-with-falling-blocks-of-color-and-hypnotic-rhythms) was closed as not constructive.  It's about identifying which game will be played at an upcoming competition, based on some teaser information and similar previous competitions.

Why was it closed?  Could someone please explain why this was not constructive?

While I probably won't be able to select an answer (for sure) until the end of the month, this question will have a definite answer.

Please let me know if any edits to the question would make a useful question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I probably won't be able to select an answer (for sure) until the end of the month

In other words, all the answers are guesses.  Only the answerer with magical powers to see the future, or with luck on their side, can accurately answer the question.  When put that way, can you see why it's unconstructive?

From the [FAQ](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq):

> [S]ite policies prohibit questions of the following types:
>
> - [...]
> - Speculation of the future [...]

After the month is over, your question will be entirely useless (Too Localized).  It also amounts to "mindless social fun", which is [discouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/) (point 6).

Comment: With any id-this-game question, all answers are guesses (until the OP selects one).  With this question, I **will** be able to select an answer, after some time.  (I do think that Lumines is the most likely answer - the comic provides strong evidence.)

Comment: @KatieK And when you do accept an answer, will the question be of use to anyone, at all?